# C# Large Tree Iteration

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, iteration, tree-traversal

I have a large result set assembled in a parent/child relationship.  I need to walk the tree and display the results to the user.

I've done this before using recursion, but because my result set may be large, I want to avoid the possibility of receiving a StackOverflowException.

I found the following [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx) on MSDN which uses a Stack.  The problem I'm having is because a stack is last-in first-out, my data doesn't appear properly.  I'd like it to look like the following:

```
LeveL 1
Level 1.1
Level 1.1.1 
Level 1.1.2 
Level 1.2 
Level 1.2.1 
Level 1.2.2
```

But it looks like:

```
LeveL 1
Level 1.2 
Level 1.2.2 
Level 1.2.1 
Level 1.1 
Level 1.1.2 
Level 1.1.1
```

Any ideas?

Here is an example of my code.  Assuming the `DataTable dt` has the following columns: ID, ParentID, and Text

```
    private struct Item
    {
        public string Text;
        public int ID;
        public int ParentID;
    }

    private void BuildView()
    {
        Stack<Item> itemTree = new Stack<Item>(40);

        //Get All Parent Nodes
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.RowFilter = "ParentID = 0";

        //Add the parent nodes to the stack
        foreach (DataRowView drv in dv)
        {
            Item item = new Item();
            item.Text = drv["Text"].ToString();
            item.ID = drv["ID"].ToString();
            item.ParentID = drv["ParentID"].ToString();
            itemTree.Push(item);
        }

        //Go through the stack one node at a time
        while (itemTree.Count > 0)
        {
            Item currentItem = itemTree.Pop();
            Debug.WriteLine(currentItem.Text);

            //Get children of current node
            dv.RowFilter = String.Format("ParentID = {0}", currentItem.ID);
            if (dv.Count > 0)
            {
                //Add child nodes to the stack
                foreach (DataRowView drvChild in dv)
                {
                    Item item = new Item();
                    item.Text = drvChild["Text"].ToString();
                    item.ID = drvChild["ID"].ToString();
                    item.ParentID = drvChild["ParentID"].ToString();
                    itemTree.Push(item);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push your items onto the stack in the reverse order, i.e. 2 before 1.

Example:

```
// suppose I want to push children[] onto the stack

for (int i = children.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   stack.Push(children[i]);
}
```

To do this in your code, try the following `for-each` statement:

```
foreach (DataRowView drvChild in dv.Reverse())
```

Comment: @Niyaz: Updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Yeah. But can you explain how this will give the required answer? I cannot understand.

Comment: @Niyaz: I think this works for the OP's particular way of using the stack. Guess it depends on how you are using the stack for the traversal.

Comment: Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @djdouma: I think your way is optimal for the desired output.

Answer (score 3):

In the current algorithm you are going for the right child first.

Make it left child first. Thats all.

For example, in your code there may be something like:

```
node = node.rightChild()
```

Change it to

```
node = node.leftChild()
```

This is the general solution for this kind of issues.

Since the MSDN implementation does not expose this kind of code, I cannot comment on that.

Comment: I think there's a typo there... both lines of code are identical.

Answer (score 0):

If it's simply the ordering that is providing concern, change from using a Stack to using a Queue. They're the same for practical purposes with the difference that a Queue is first in first out.

Comment: Using a queue changes it to a breadth-first traversal, instead of the desired depth-first traversal.

Comment: Zach, Not necessarily. It becomes breadth first only if you do breadth first.
But usually we use queue in breadth first searches.

Comment: If I use a queue, the data appears like this.
Level 1 
Level 1.1 
Level 1.2 
Level 1.1.1 
Level 1.1.2 
Level 1.2.1 
Level 1.2.2

Answer (score 0):

By changing my iteration of the child nodes in reverse order, they display as desired

```
//Add child nodes to the stack
for (int i = dv.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    DataRowView drvChild = dv[i];
    Item item = new Item();
    item.Text = drvChild["Text"].ToString();
    item.ID = drvChild["ID"].ToString();
    item.ParentID = drvChild["ParentID"].ToString();
    itemTree.Push(item);
}
```

Comment: Typo? Index i doesn't seem to be used.